# How to call method from #define .h class

Tags: objective-c

I need to call a method from macros class I have.

This is the code line in My macros.h class :

```
#define checkinternet Connection.IsConnecetionToInternet()
```

And I want to call a method from anther class that return true/false.

It is possible ?

Comment: from other class you may call `if (checkinternet)` and i believe this macro (ultimately the method) will return true/false. You may declare methods as macros, but you will not be getting the return values, since macros are not executed at compile time, it only gets replaced and compiled.